# Navigation bar style in popover view controller

Tags: ipad, split, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, popover

In iPhone SDK 4.2.3, use default Split View template to cook-up a dummy application.

In landscape mode, the master view uses default navigation bar style. In portrait mode, the master view uses black navigation bar style inside the popover. How can i change the bar style/tint color to make it consistent for both views?

I've tried to do this in split view delegate method, but it doesn't work.

```
pc.contentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
pc.contentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I've also tried to explicitly set the navigation bar style in the master view controller class, but that doesn't seem to have any impact as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, i can safely say that it's not possible.